# how to get back delete responsitory from source tree

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, data-recovery

I suddenly deleted the local repo that contains all of my code. Now all of my code is deleted. I do not know where the deleted files went or any method that can help me to restore all the code.

What I have done, is right click on the repo-name and then select delete

Comment: What kind of repository are we talking about?

Comment: a local. On sourcetree ,I click Clone/New then choose Create new responsitory then I put the folder which contains all my code in Destination path. After that right click on the repo name and choose delete repo there is warning but I dont really pay attention about it

Comment: Well there's a lesson for you. Is it in the trash?

Answer (score 1):

Don't you have any save on a back-up system? Maybe on an external drive or something like that?

Have you checked your trash bin? (If you're on Linux, check ~/.local/share/Trash/files)

Just a little advice: Configure an automatic back-up on an other drive at a fixed time (once a week). That way, even if you loose the latest modifications, you don't loose the whole code.